# Limitation in number of entries in System variables Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

I've encountered that there might be a limit of how many entries you can have in System Variables in Environment Variables, can someone verify my suspicion?

I'm ***not*** talking about how many characters can exist in Path.

Answer (score 4):

There is no limit to the **number** of variables AFAIK, but there are some limits to their size (dependent on system version):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> The maximum size of a user-defined environment variable is 32,767
>   characters. There is no technical limitation on the size of the
>   environment block. However, there are practical limits depending on
>   the mechanism used to access the block. For example, a batch file
>   cannot set a variable that is longer than the maximum command line
>   length.
>
> Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The maximum size of the
>   environment block for the process is 32,767 characters. Starting with
>   Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008, there is no technical
>   limitation on the size of the environment block.

*n.b. command line length they mention is 8191 chars.*

Comment: Can the maximum size be decreased by a policy setting or at all?
We're talking about an Windows 7 64-bit computer.

Comment: @Roger I have no idea... it's certainly possible to add, amend or remove variables via gpo though. Maybe if you edit your question and describe exactly what you wanted to achieve or what problem you face someone will be able to help.